# Implementing if - else if using bitwise operators

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, logic, bit-manipulation

Assume that the value of `test` is `1` or `0`. Here I can implement the following if statement using bitwise operators as below.

```
if (test)
    output = a;
else
    output = b;
```

*Using bit wise operators*

```
output = (((test << 31) >> 31) & a) | (((test << 31) >> 31) & b);
```

Now I want to implement the following if statements using bitwise operators.

```
if (test1)
    output = a;
else if (test2)
    output = b;
else if (test3)
    output = c;
else
    output = d;
```

The values of `test1`, `test2`, `test3` are either `0` or `1`.

 Any suggestions to do that ?

Comment: Are you allowed to use not `!`?

Comment: `+` is not a bitwise operator.

Comment: Also, there are no loops here.

Comment: What's type of `test`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I used `+` for `|`. There is no chance of overflow here.

Comment: @kotlomoy `test` is of `int` type

Comment: @noufal: You missed OliCharlesworth's point. You specifically stipulated to use bit-wise operators. If `+` is allowed, then your requirements are unclear. Is anything that is guaranteed not to overflow also allowed?

Comment: @MarceloCantos You are right...I have made an edit...

Comment: @noufal: Thanks, but you still haven't addressed the very first comment, above. What is the motivation for this requirement? Is it branch-avoidance, an intellectual exercise, homework, or something else?

Comment: @MarceloCantos yeah...intellectual exercise..

Comment: @FDinoff `!` is allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you meant this for your original if statement.

```
output = (((test << 31) >> 31) & a) | (((!test << 31) >> 31) & b);
```

Not in front of test so that this isn't a+b when test is 1 and 0 when test is 0 and I replaced `+` with `|` because each case should be 0 except for the one you want.

To do the cascaded if else if else statements you could rewrite the expression so that 
they are dependent on the previous test.

```
if (test1)
    output = a
if (!test1 & test2)
    output = b
if (!test1 & !test2 & test3)
    output = c
if (!test1 & !test2 & !test3)
    output = d
```

This leads to an expression like this for all the if else ifs.

```
output = (((test1 << 31) >> 31) & a)
         | ((((!test1 & test2) << 31) >> 31) & b)
         | ((((!test1 & !test2 & test3) << 31) >> 31) & c)
         | ((((!test1 & !test2 & !test3) << 31) >> 31) & d)
```

Comment: Why the wasteful and unportable ((test << 31) >> 31) instead of (test & 1) ?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Its very unportable but its supposed to make a true value 0xFFFFFFFF and a false value 0x00000000. This happens because test1 is assumed to be signed and 32 bits. Shifting the 1 all the way to the highest position and then shifting it back fills it with ones because the computer is doing a signed shift. This is not equivalent to (test & 1)

Comment: Then that's just (-(test & 1)). Big shifts just seem wasteful.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker That would turn 1 into 0xFFFFFFFE and 0 into 0xFFFFFFFF. These aren't the same. Also the test with  `& 1` is pointless since test is assumed to be 0 or 1 according to the question

Comment: Um, no, look again. (test & 1) evaluates to either 0 or 1, then the negative sign makes it 0 or -1, which is 0xFFFFFFFF. If we already know that it's 0 or 1, so much the better, then we just want `-test`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Woops I saw `~`. But I guess that would be sufficient. But I'm not sure if the OP want a minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have be bitwise operators? What about:

```
output = (    test1) * a +
         (1 - test1) * ((    test2) * b +
                        (1 - test2) * ((    test3) * c +
                                       (1 - test3) * d));
```

Another possibility, only using bit-wise operators, is this:

```
switch ((test1 << 2) | (test2 << 1) | test3) {
    case 0: output = d; break;
    case 1: output = c; break;
    case 2:
    case 3: output = b; break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7: output = a; break;
}
```

If you're lucky (and if it speeds things up), the compiler will implement the switch using a jump table.

You really have to question, though, whether these tricksy solutions offer enough of a speed bump (if they do) to justify the additional complexity. I assume you're trying to avoid branching.